# Should I re-use my view page for Show/Add/Update page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I don't want to repeat the form elements if possible.

The actual form elements for Create/Update/Show are pretty much the exact same.

Except for the 'Show' action the form elements shouldnt' be editable.

But for update/create the form elements are the exact same.

Is it possible to create a single view page for this?

(MVC2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the view level I'd apply the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), i.e. have one separate view for every action.

But you can include the same form into multiple views if you extract it as a [Partial View](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/638_Understanding_Partial_Views_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx).

Comment: Agreed. One thing to add - don't start adding code into the partial such as "if from action A show this, if from action B show this, etc." Before long you'll have one partial that's shared and is great for the SRP except it's doing separate things inside to coincide for minor differences for each action it's acting upon.

Comment: but will I create 2 views in the end for 'show' and 'edit/add'?  because show won't have input tags, while edit/add will.  so if I need to add a new field, I have to edit 2 view files.

Comment: @codecompleting show differs from edit/add anyway, so yes, you will have to modify both the partial view for edit/add and the view for show when adding a field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a partial view for your shared form elements here.